# Remove box-shadow on Active Cell in datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable, slds-styling-hooks

I've been pouring over [slds styling hook docs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#Styling-Hooks-Naming-Conventions) and [datatable docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types_styling) and I cannot figure out how to remove this box shadow when the cell has focus.

[image: checked radio button with custom coloring and wrong box shadow color]

I know for sure it's box shadow because when I uncheck this box in chrome dev tools it goes away

[image: box shadow css property]

I've tried all of these combinations in the :host selector

```
--slds-c-table-gridcell-shadow-box-has-focus: none;
--slds-c-table-shadow-box-has-focus: none;
--slds-c-table-gridcell-shadow-box-is-active: none;
--slds-c-table-shadow-box-is-active: none;
--slds-c-table-border-is-active: none;
--slds-c-table-gridcell-is-active: none;
```

I've also tried adding a class to the CSS file in the LWC bundle and then setting that through the cell attributes in the JS but I'm thinking it's missing the active part so that didn't work either.

CSS

```
.box-shadow-delete { box-shadow: none; }
```

JS

```
{label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', cellAttributes: { class: 'box-shadow-delete'}}
```

Am I missing something in the docs?? Or misunderstanding how the styling hooks work with cells? Any help or ideas on how to fix this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which styling hooks are available for a lightning component can be found in its blueprint page under lightningdesignsystem.com [Here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#site-main-content) is the blueprint for datatable. Also, class you mention in cellAttributes must be slds classes. Custom css classes are not supported. One thing you can try is, reassign value to `--lwc-brandAccessible` variable.